# GIT pull fails on https only on build server

Tags: git, ssh, https, bitbucket, pull

I know it is a popular question but i searched all answers and didn't find a scenario like I have.

I use bitbucket repo server and local git.

when I use from cmd prompt: git pull 
I have no problems. It doesn't ask for credential and command is successful.

But when I use the same exact syntax (git pull) but from my build server(TeamCity) which has its own command line step in build, the pull fails with:

```
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
[16:01:51][Step 13/13] bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
[16:01:51][Step 13/13] error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
[16:01:51][Step 13/13] fatal: could not read Password for 'https://AviLevak@bitbucket.org/': No error
```

I read the answers saying just switch to ssh. I didn't succeed in that since the bitbucket site is non helpful to say the least.

I need a patient answer ,please:) don't just direct me to other answers that are close to mine. I need to understand how is it that pull worked for me till now but when the build server tries to do it, it needs credential all of a sudden. and how to fix it.

If it's unsolvable then please if you ever tried to add ssh to bitbucket help me figure out why I don't even have the option to create one on my bitbucket. the settings page doesn't show the option on this repo.

Comment: btw - ALL in the same machine of course

Comment: Which operating system? It's possible that your git client is using a credential manager that TeamCity can't or won't use.

Comment: windows 10 unfortunately :)